# Python - Intensity map without interpolation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to make an intensity plot.

I have three lists of x,y,z values, imported from real data: `x_list, y_list, z_list`. Each of these lists contain 200 values. Therefore there is a corresponding value of z for each x,y couple.

I have tried the following, after some search on the web and another question on StackOverflow:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

data = np.loadtxt('data.d')
x_list = data[:,0]
y_list = data[:,1]
z_list = data[:,2]

from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

f = interp2d(x_list,y_list,z_list,kind="linear")

x_coords = np.arange(min(x_list),max(x_list)+1)
y_coords = np.arange(min(y_list),max(y_list)+1)
Z = f(x_coords,y_coords)

fig = plt.imshow(Z,
           extent=[min(x_list),max(x_list),min(y_list),max(y_list)],
           origin="lower")


fig.axes.set_autoscale_on(False)
plt.scatter(x_list,y_list,400,facecolors='none')

plt.show()
```

This uses interpolation, and I am not sure that it is exactly what I need. 
Is there a way to plot ONLY the 200 values of z, corresponding to the 200 x,y couples, for which I have a given value, withuot interpolation? Obviously I still need some kind of "intensity relation", I cannot just have a scatter plot without a way of interpreting the "intensity" of the 200 z values.

Comment: It's pretty obvious, why the values are interpolated, no? f = interp2d(..., Z = f(..., plt.imshow(Z...

Comment: @tommy.carstensen yes but I don't want the interpolation. If this means using something else rather than plt.imshow, that's fine, but I don't want interpolation

Comment: You can possibly do `Z = np.reshape(z_list, (max(x_list),max(y_list)))`. Kindly let me know, if that works. Thanks.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen thanks, unfortunately it doesn't work.It says ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to display xyz points in a 2D graph where z-value would be represented by a color. If that is correct the solution is as simple as stating `facecolors=z_list` in your scatter plot:

```
data = np.random.rand(200,3)
x_list = data[:,0]
y_list = data[:,1]
z_list = data[:,2]

plt.scatter(x_list,y_list,200,facecolors=z_list)

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Example output :
[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works and that's what I want. Now I just have to figure out how to use some kind of logarithm scale on facecolors=z_list. This is due to the fact that my 200 values in z_list are all very close to each other, so if you simply apply your recipe to my case you don't see much of a difference in the intensities