# How do I make a intensity plot with coordinates on map in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

Say I have a data set as the following:

```
lat  |  long | intensity
22 | 22 | -100
30 | 30 | -50
```

And I would like to plot coordinates on a Hong Kong map and the color indicates the intensity using python. Something like this picture in [Python - Intensity map without interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894926/python-intensity-map-without-interpolation) but points are on a map instead. Is there a library that I can do this easily?

Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Is this a [tag:python] or [tag:r] question? Please choose.

Comment: python is preferred.

Comment: Try `Plotly Scatter_mapbox` [link](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/)

Comment: is there another option? mapbox requires my credit card ... Thanks